# Can I merge multiple data extensions?

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, sql, personalization

I am doing a task that requires personalization from multiple data extensions. Can I use Query Activities to merge them together? And also, can I use the finished merged data extension in my landing page? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will simply need to use [JOIN](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) statement in your SQL query. There are multiple types of JOIN, each one serving a different purpose - depending on how you want your data extensions combined.

[Here is a good article](https://mateuszdabrowski.pl/docs/sql/sfmc-sql-join/) by [Mateusz Dabrowski](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/91679/mateusz-d%C4%85browski) explaining the use of JOINS in SFMC

And yes, you will be able to use the output DE in your landing page. How? Again - it depends on your use case.